# Manually populate a Pivot Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, microsoft-excel-2011

This is really a stupid question because I am supposed to know the answer.

I have a data file that looks like this:

```
Tech    ||  Workdate   || Fail || Manual
Joe     || 2013-05-23  ||   6  ||   1
Joe     || 2013-05-24  ||   2  ||   1
Tom     || 2013-05-23  ||   0  ||   2
Tom     || 2013-05-24  ||   2  ||   0
```

I do believe that what I am trying to accomplish is obvious, except to me. Here it is:

```
-> Joe ||              ||   8  ||   2
       ||  2013-05-23  ||   6  ||   1
       ||  2013-05-24  ||   2  ||   1

-> Tom ||              ||   2  ||   2
       ||  2013-05-23  ||   0  ||   2
       ||  2013-05-24  ||   2  ||   0
```

The pivot table wizard will only accept math functions such as count in the data field.  I don't want the count of the 'fail' and 'Manual'.  That's always going to be 1 for both.  I need the actual values with a summation under each tech's name.  Where am I going wrong?

Here's some helpful details:
Macbook Pro, OS 10.8.3
Excel Mac, v2011, 14.1.3

Answer (score 4):

The following Pivot Table setting should produce what you are looking for:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to click on the item in the Values section, choose "Value Field Settings," and then change from Count to Sum.